# How does a program know what to read in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe

How does the unix command line program know what file to read?

For example:

```
 cat someFile | foo
```

How does the program `foo` know which file to read, and which process is responsible for opening and reading the file from disk?

Comment: `foo` does not read a file. `cat` reads the file, then passes the content of the file through a pipe, to `foo`. `foo` just reads the stuff coming out of the pipe. Therefore `foo` can not know what file it came from.

Answer (score 2):

`foo` does not know what file to read, it (presumably) just reads from its standard input stream.  This data stream is connected by the shell to the standard output stream of the `cat` command.  This "administrational plumbing" is done by the shell as it starts the two processes (they would run concurrently).

In the example in the question, it is `cat` that will open the file for reading, read it and pass the data on its standard output.

You might as well ask "How does `cat` know where to write the result?"  The answer is that it writes to its standard output stream, connected by the shell to the standard input stream of the `foo` command.  Likewise, the standard output stream of the `foo` command is connected to the terminal by the shell since there are no further pipes or redirections for this command.

---

The pipeline that you show,

```
cat someFile | foo
```

is functionally identical to

```
foo <somefile
```

Here I've deleted `cat` since it's not really needed.  The shell will connect the standard input stream of `foo` to the given file, so the effect will be the same (`foo` would be able to read the contents of `somefile` from its standard input stream).

In this last command, `foo` still does not know that it reads data coming from a file called `somefile`.  It also does not know it's no longer reading from the output of `cat`.  It just reads its standard input stream as before.

It is now the shell that will open the file `somefile` for reading, but the shell will not read anything from the file, just hook the standard input stream up with the opened file for `foo` to read from.

---

Note that we don't know what the `foo` command does, whether it actually does *anything* with its standard input stream, or whether it expects a filename to read from on its command line.  This sort of information would be available in the manual of the `foo` program.

In the case where `foo` actually *needs* to be told to read from a specific file by giving it a pathname on the command line, you may use

```
foo somefile
```

Now `foo` would be responsible for both opening and reading from the file.

If the file has to be processed in some way (assuming "`cat`" is a more complicated process that actually modifies the data read from `somefile`):

```
cat somefile >newfile
foo newfile
rm newfile
```

I.e., process the file and save the result in a new temporary file, then pass the name of the temporary file to `foo`. Then remove the temporary file.

Or, with a shell that understands process substitutions (like `bash`):

```
foo <( cat somefile )
```

Here, the shell would arrange for the output of `cat somefile` to be written to a temporary file (or named pipe, it does not really matter), and the pathname of that data would be inserted in place of the process substitution `<( ... )`.  `foo` would then open that as its file to read from.

In this final example, `cat` would open the original file and read from it while `foo` would open whatever pathname the shell gives it (where the output of `cat` is found) and read from it.

Answer (score 1):

In `cat someFile | foo` there are three elements:

1. `cat someFile`
2. the pipe `|`
3. `foo`

And now what's going on:

1. `cat` knows it should read `someFile`, because that's how it was called, and so the sell tells it the details. Namely, `someFile` is a parameter here and all parameters are passed on to the called app.
2. The pipe is what makes shell fork subshells and start processes in them, as well as arrange the subshells and processes, setting inter alia their input and output. That's how `foo` gets the input from `cat`.
3. `foo` is called the same as `cat` before. But after step two (which in fact is step 1 in the shell) the input to `foo` comes from `cat`. That's how the pipeline was called.

Answer (score -1):

You wrote two commands: `cat someFile` and `foo`. First command has to read `someFile` and writes it to `standard output` which is redirected to `pipe`. The next command reads the data from its `standard input` to which is redirected to the output from the `pipe`.

Standard input, standard output and standard error output are the basic linux terms and redirection and pipe are the most powerfull principle to flow the data between the programs. Pleas, look for these terms to understand the basics linux command line.